# Firebase auth login not working after logout until cookies are cleared

Tags: firebase, authentication, cookies, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am building a social media web app using Nextjs, and express. I am using firebase for the auth.

When I log out of one account, there are cookies still in storage but the token is no longer within the cookie. When I log back into either the same account or another account the login page just refreshes throwing no errors and the only way to fix is to clear all the cookies. There is a new cookie with a token in it but the user isn't allowed to log in.

`await firebase.auth().signOut();` This is the method I am using for sign out, it is nested two levels up in components, I am unsure whether this changes anything.

```
await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        window.location.href = "/authenticated/home";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        const message = error.message;
        toast.error(message);
      });
```

This is the method I am using to log in as a user.

Please could someone advise what is happening, thank you.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/Thomas13702/socialmedia_frontend)

Comment: Try passing a flag to disable persistence.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am wanting some persistence, but something seems to be blocking the login function after log out, I am looking for persistence similar to Facebook, where you're logged in until you press log out but then you can log back in.